# King's Indian Attack position analysis

Tags: analysis, kings-indian-attack

[image: Kings Indian Attack Position]

So, after some 20 moves, we have reached this position.

1. Who is better ?
2. What should be the ideal plan/threat for both white and black ?

Answer (score 1):

Note that Q1 can nowadays safely be answered by simply using an engine. My gut feeling that White stands bad (bad bishop, off Nh4, rest also stands around the botany and doesn't do anything, open king, no attack whatsover to compensate) was vindicated by Stockfish, but I didn't guess it was already that abysmal (-2.5, almost a piece in a materially equal position!). If it is Black to move (you didn't say), immediately N-b6-d7-c5 follows, even -3.3. It is very indicative in the first case that the computer playing White (in the first variant after stabilizing at depth 22) does not even attempt to defend Pb2 after advancing c5 (to get some breathing space), Black answering again Nbd7, then Bc6, then Reb8.

Summing up:

- You must pay me for playing this lavatory for White.
- OTB human play: White's best plan might be a desperate pawn roller on the king side (KIA/KID  standard plan) and praying to the preferred god that some swindle is possible. Black simply gangs up everything on the queen side weaknesses (KIA/KID  standard plan), maybe throwing in some prophylaxis like Nh7 if White goes desperate.